# Fail to kill process on android

Tags: android, kill-process, activity-finish

I am developing a tiny app, it might contains several activities, and in `MainActivity`, there's a button aims to kill the whole process, here's what I do in the `OnCLick`:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
MainActivity.this.finish();
```

I tested it on my phone. It did exit the activity and backed to my home page, but I long pressed the home page to check the current running process on my phone and found that it's still regarded as a running process. If I open it again, it would be just like a restarted one. Does anyone know how to solve this problem, or is it just a bug that an Android phone might have?

Comment: Any error logs you have ?

Comment: The long-press on home brings up recent apps, not necessarily running apps.

Comment: add the tag kill process in the manifest

Comment: Seriously? Three reviewers thought an edit that capitalized the word "it" multiple times in the middle of sentences was correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
        android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
        System.exit(0);
```